# Do we 'wish' something negative?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, word-usage

While taking an online test, I came across this question that confused me for a while.

> **I ______ it doesn't rain tomorrow, I'm going for a picnic.**
>
> A.   wait 
> B.   expect
> C.   hope
> D.   wish

I clicked *hope* but unfortunately, the site gives the result and not the answer.

Question: Whilst it is beyond doubt that neither *A* nor *B* is correct and *C* looks perfect, *D* does not look totally wrong.

Is *wish* possible there? In ***any*** circumstances? Do we ***wish*** something negative? And yes, did I click on the correct option?

Answer (score 8):

In this case, *wish* is semantically but not grammatically correct. *Hope* is the correct answer.

You can absolutely *wish* that something wouldn't happen in the future. This conveys a meaning very similar to *hope*, but suggests that you think the desired negative circumstance (e.g. *not raining*) is rather unlikely.

In the example, *wish* is not correct, because *I wish it doesn't rain* is ungrammatical. You should use *wouldn't* with *wish* when talking about future circumstances. *Couldn't* also works, if you're wishing for a denial of any capability, but that doesn't make much sense when talking about weather.

Here's an example of a common usage of *wishing* for something negative:

> I wish you wouldn't do that.

This is said to someone exhibiting some habitual and unpleasant behavior as a polite way of asking them to stop doing it, both now and in the future.

Comment: never thought it that way. Maybe, non-native's limitations ;) +1

Comment: But "I wish it wouldn't rain tomorrow" has an interesting semantic twist: I can only say that if I am fairly sure that it _will_ rain tomorrow. I am wishing that it would be different. The original sentence has no such prescient  quality at all.

Comment: Is their a particular reason that hope/doesn't go together and wish/wouldn't do? I hope it doesn't rain tomorrow, I wish it wouldn't rain tomorrow. I feel it may have something to do with @oerkelens point, hope sounds like you have no clue about the chances, but wish sounds like you think the opposite is goign to happen.

Comment: @Tom Good question; it is related to oerkelens' remark. A wish is necessarily hypothetical, so it requires an irrealis verb like *would* or *could*. *Did* is realis and it doesn't make sense to wish for something that's materialized already.